# Get content from mdf file / Import to Excel

Tags: database, excel, csv, mdf

I have a `.mdf` file (some GB) that contains data from an old application. However I need to work with some information that is stored in this database. Different to similar questions I have not developed this application, I do not have a SQL Server running, I just have the file.

I already installed MDF Viewer (http://www.sqlmdfviewer.org/) and I can see the information that I need there in two tables but this tool can really only display the content, it is not possible to export or even copy/paste.

I have also installed SQL Server Management Studio Express as this software was mentioned in other questions but if I want to open the mdf file I get an error "The operation could not be completed".

Is there some tool like MDF Viewer that can also export the content of a table? Excel, CSV, ... something that I can read and work with?

Comment: Why can't you just install the *FREE* SQL Server Express? Install it, attach the `.mdf` to your server, extract the data - done!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I installed SQL Server 2012 but unfortunately it is not that easy. First the database was not starting at all. Googled, tried different settings and now the process is running but I cannot login and connect to my local SQLEXPRESS database. Login failed (Error: 18456); Tried many fixes but nothing helps. Maybe because I have a domain user but the database is local?! Even re-installed with also local access but "sa" is not working.
If I want to open the .mdf in the Management Studio I get an "Out of memory" exception..